# How to play audio with narration in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, narrator

I need to play audio file with text narrating the sound being played in my application. Is there any library for the proper sync of audio file with text or its subtitles. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/taglib/taglib try out this

Comment: @Sport : I couldn't find there any documentation about how to integrate taglib in iOS if you know please share the details.